# Iterate over bundles to create entity bundle class for each

Tags: entities, 9

I'm curious if anyone has a way to produce an entity bundle class for several bundles at once. For example:

```php
function MYMODULE_entity_bundle_info_alter(&$bundles) {

  // My array of different content types.
  $target_bundles = ['page', 'article'];

  // Iterate over the content types.
  foreach($target_bundle as $bundle) {

    $Bundle = ucfirst($bundle); // page to Page
    $bundles['node'][$bundle]['class'] = $Bundle::class; // Page::class

  }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is the `$Bundle::class` part doesn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you have the class names wrong,  I would debug the return for  `EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface->getBundleInfo('node);`. and refer to 'ContentEntityStorageBase'

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. I edited my code sample because of some errors. The error I'm getting is: **Fatal error:** Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name. This got me pointed in the right direction. I didn't understand that `::class` simply returns the full namespace of the class. When I added that into my string concatenation for the $Bundle variable, everything worked. I'll post the working code in the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After some poking around, I realized the error I was getting:
**Fatal error:** Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name

Long story short, my problem was I didn't understand that `::class` simply returns the full namespace of the class itself. Once I added in the full namespace to my `$Bundle` variable, everything worked nicely. The code below provides an efficient way to assign multiple entity bundles to their respective classes.

```php
function mymodule_entity_bundle_info_alter(&$bundles) {

  // Array of content type machine names.
  $target_bundles = ['page', 'article'];

  // Iterate over the content types.
  foreach($target_bundle as $bundle) {

    // Turn 'page' to 'Page' and add the full namespace.
    $Bundle = 'Drupal\mymodule\Entity\' . ucfirst($bundle);

    $bundles['node'][$bundle]['class'] = $Bundle;
  }
}
```